# How to slice an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

So I have an annoyingly long array as a result of scraping a website. I want to slice this array into objects with seven properties.

**I want to get from this:**

```
  [
  ".:j:.Junque.Shoppe",
  "Texas",
  "Liberty",
  "253",
  "0",
  "2",
  "21 minutes, 24 seconds",
  "[Neptune]",
  "Pennsylvania",
  "Liberty",
  "50",
  "0",
  "2",
  "2 minutes, 7 seconds"
  //40 more sets like this
  ]
```

**To this:**

```
[
   {
      name: ".:j:.Junque.Shoppe",
      system: "Texas",
      region: "Liberty",
      ping: "253",
      loss: "0",
      lag: "2",
      online: "21 minutes, 24 seconds"
   },
   {
      name: "[Neptune]"
      //(...)
   },
   //(...)
 ]
```

Comment: Show us how you're trying to do it?

Comment: Suggest you fix this at source when you do the scraping

Comment: Improved title grammar and overall small formatting fixes of the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with this function (note the array of keys shown in below code snippet):

```
function sliceToObj(original, keys) {
    if (original.length % keys.length !== 0) return false;
    var res = [];
    var obj = {};
    original.forEach(function (val, i) {
        if (i > 0 && i % keys.length === 0) {
            res.push(obj);
            obj = {};
        }
        obj[keys[i % keys.length]] = val;
    });
    res.push(obj);
    return res;
}
```

---

```js
function sliceToObj(original, keys) {
    if (original.length % keys.length !== 0) return false;
    var res = [];
    var obj = {};
    original.forEach(function (val, i) {
        if (i > 0 && i % keys.length === 0) {
            res.push(obj);
            obj = {};
        }
        obj[keys[i % keys.length]] = val;
    });
    res.push(obj);
    return res;
}

var arr =   [
    ".:j:.Junque.Shoppe",
    "Texas",
    "Liberty",
    "253",
    "0",
    "2",
    "21 minutes, 24 seconds",
    "[Neptune]",
    "Pennsylvania",
    "Liberty",
    "50",
    "0",
    "2",
    "2 minutes, 7 seconds"
    //40 more sets like this
];
var keys = [
    'name',
    "system",
    "region",
    'ping',
    'loss',
    'lag',
    'online'
];



console.log(sliceToObj(arr, keys));
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always 7 properties and always in the correct order:

```
var parseJunk = function(arr) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 7) {
    var obj = {
      name: arr[i],
      system: arr[i+1],
      region: arr[i+2],
      ping: arr[i+3],
      loss: arr[i+4],
      lag: arr[i+5],
      online: arr[i+6]
    };

    result.push(obj);
  }

  return result;
}
```